# What technology stack does Autodesk FormIt use?

Tags: autodesk

Autodesk's [FormIt](http://formit360.autodesk.com) software exists on Windows,Web,Android and IOS.

Does anyone know what technology stack they are using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Desktop is C++ with Qt Framework. For Android is Java and for Web is HTML5 and JS

Because app is made for multiple platforms not means use same language in all. Only way to do that is using HTML5/JS in all platforms and that is not used in this case.

Comment: Doesn't xamarin with c# allow you to cover all the bases

Comment: No, Xamarin is not one stop shop for apps, like announced. In Xamarin you just have a common code but all interfaces must be created separately, because you must implement diferent API's from diferent systems.